# How to completely remove Phoronix Test Suite?

Tags: uninstall

Is the a way to completely remove Phoronix Test Suite with it's test results, installed suits, etc… from my system? I used the `.sh` installer file to install the Phoronix Test Suite on my system.

So if there is can you share the information with me

when i try to just uninstall it this is what I get

```
Package 'phoronix-test-suite' is not installed, so not removed
```

Comment: Which .sh installer (link please), and do you still have it? (if a tarball, uncompressed how you used to install)

Comment: moved archived files to home/.phoronix-test-suite and run it through terminal with sudo command. that is it.
should i just remove the executable file etc ?? I hare to do so but if there is no other way

Comment: Have you try `sudo apt-get remove phoronix-test-suite` ?

Comment: No this is what I get 
Package 'phoronix-test-suite' is not installed, so not removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation script installs the same as the deb package. Therefore install and remove the deb package.

1. Download the deb package

   ```
   cd
   wget http://phoronix-test-suite.com/releases/repo/pts.debian/files/phoronix-test-suite_5.8.0_all.deb
   ```
2. Install the test suite

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i phoronix-test-suite_5.8.0_all.deb
   ```
3. Remove the test suite

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge phoronix-test-suite
   ```

Comment: there must be an other way :D

Comment: @Levan - probably the 'easiest' as there are quite a lot of files...

Comment: @Levan Sure, use deb files instead of installer scripts :)

Comment: Well this way is not the most elegant one but gets the job done thx

Comment: @A.B. the deb and software centre version does not work on my system

Comment: Not elegant? Common =)

Answer (score 3):

phoronix have an hidden configuration folder under home directory, try remove it :

```
 rm -rf ~/.phoronix-test-suite
```

Comment: if I do that I only get rid of installed tests and suits and parameters but the phoronix-test-suite is still installed in /bin

Comment: Phew.... more than 6GBs of installed tests and still there after apt-get purge, it should be called moronix test suite.

Answer (score 2):

From examing the install script of [v5.8.1 tarball](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/download.php?file=phoronix-test-suite-5.8.1) from [here](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads), the script installs stuff to the following locations:

```
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/phoronix-test-suite
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/doc/phoronix-test-suite/
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/man/man1/phoronix-test-suite.1
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/../etc/bash_completion.d/phoronix-test-suite
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/phoronix-test-suite.png
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/applications/phoronix-test-suite.desktop
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/applications/phoronix-test-suite-launcher.desktop
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/appdata/phoronix-test-suite.appdata.xml
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/../usr/lib/systemd/system/phoromatic-client.service
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/../usr/lib/systemd/system/phoromatic-systemd/phoromatic-server.service
(probably:)
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/mime/packages/openbenchmarking-mime.xml
$DESTDIR$INSTALL_PREFIX/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/application-x-openbenchmarking.png
```

Where by default:

- `$DESTDIR` is not set, so ignored
- `$INSTALL_PREFIX` = `/usr`

So if you ran the install script without options or changing it, you should be able to remove it by running `rm /usr/share/man/man1/phoronix-test-suite.1`, `rm -r /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite`, etc.

By the way there is are packages available (e.g. http://phoronix-test-suite.com/releases/repo/pts.debian/files/phoronix-test-suite_5.8.0_all.deb ) - using packages if they are available is usually best/less annoying.